# PHP Curl, error: Browser must support session cookies?

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I am getting an error on the browser saying:

**HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Date: Fri, 06 May 2011 20:25:28 GMT Server: IBM_HTTP_Server/6.0.2.43 Apache/2.0.47 (Unix) $WSEP: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000HpGRXpuwrdY_u0k-ecHKAFK:14ekdcv70; Path=/ Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Language: en Error 500: Browser must support session cookies.**

How to solve this problem?

here what I did:

```
session_start();

$postData = http_build_query($_GET);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\BuiltinObjectToken-VerisignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://zzzzzz.zzzzz.co.uk/zzz/zzzz/" . $form_link );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postDataCapcha);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $PagaeCapcha = curl_exec($ch); 

exit($PagaeCapcha);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000HpGRXpuwrdY_u0k-ecHKAFK:14ekdcv70; Path=/
```

This is the response header which **initially** sets a session cookie. This one will not get stored in your `cookiefile` jar. It's a *temporary* cookie, and you are throwing it away.

You will have to first issue a requesting request that points to the e.g. homepage. And only afterwards send the actual data request to the desired endpoint /zzz/zzzz/.

Comment: Did you mean it should be something like this as example: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "0000HpGRXpuwrdY_u0k-ecHKAFK:14ekdcv70"); IF not, can you provide example please?

Comment: No. That's not what I meant. But to sum it up better: just call `curl_exec()` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you're sending the name of the session that YOUR copy of PHP has created. This is almost certainly not the name of the session that the `.co.uk` server has created. So it's seeing that as your "browser" not supporting cookies - it tries to set a session cookie named 'JSESSIONSID', but you send back a cookie named 'PHP_SESSID' (or whatever).

Comment: Oh I see, so what do I need to do solve it? In the header response, it say "JSESSIONID" is that got anything to do with it?

Comment: You need to capture the cookie the other server sends to you, and send that back verbatim. You may have to split the request up into two stages - one to get the session cookie initially, then your actual request to fetch the data you want.